# robocopy fails copy with multiple options

Tags: robocopy

Using robocopy trying to copy files from network drive to local workstation folder with some options, but getting the error 123, 1314. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect and a required privilege is not held by the client.

```
robocopy "\\xfolder\xyz" "c:\test" /MT:8 /MIR /ZB /COPYALL /R:0 /W:0 /MON:1 /MOT:05
```

Is the options I am using is right, or is there any changes required to avoid these errors. Could someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`robocopy \\xfolder\xyz c:\test /MIR /ZB /COPYALL /R:0 /W:0 /MON:1 /MOT:5`

Note the extra `\` for the UNC path.  Using `"` is not necessary when there is no space in the path. `/MT:8` is also unecessary because 8 is the default value. For `/MOT` there is no need for a leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

Testing this myself, I had to remove the inverted comma's - error I got was no destination specified.

Solved the rights issue - CMD session needs to run in Administrator mode. /COPYALL and Backup Mode needs elevated privileges (audit manager, backup operator)